# Book where a girl discovers she's a cyborg

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, cyborg

I read it years ago in high school & it's haunted me since.

I only remember a few things with clarity, but one of them is that she goes to a support group following an accident that destroyed her memory, and the other is that at one point she deliberately hurts herself severely enough that her parents (both of whom are alive) can no longer hide the truth, that she is almost entirely synthetic except for the core part of her brain.

That's as sci-fi as it gets. There's no big plot about a robot uprising or anything, and it's definitely not *The Adoration of Jenna Fox*. I checked.

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but if this sounds at all familiar, please help me. If it means anything, I used to be completely convinced it was called 'The Butterfly Heart', after what her mother in story claims the surviving part of her brain is called, but apparently that's wrong. 'Butterfly' might be in the title, though, because I was *really* convinced.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: Interesting because "butterfly" is what Jenna's dad calls the surviving bit of her original brain.

Comment: If this isn't *The Adoration of Jenna Fox* Mary Pearson should be suing the author for copyright violation.

Comment: One of these; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=Butterfly&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=contains&TERM_2=The&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: How did you check that it wasn't *The Adoration of Jenna Fox*? Because yeah, Butterfly bit of the brain, summer camp-y group thingy, this is checking off a lotta boxes.

Comment: It's probably not but it reminds me a little of Alita

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s *Skinned* by Robin Wasserman. Closeish to *The Adoration of Jenna Fox*, and if I remember correctly she has some memory issues. Can’t remember if any organic parts are saved. Might also be *Mila 2.0*.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. Any other info you could [edit] in with some extra details would be great. Take a look at [answer] for some helpful tips

Comment: If you have two different books to offer up as answers, it's better to write them as separate answers. You will get more points, and if the querant answers with a, "that's it" comment, it's clear which one is the correct answer.